# MacPorts says I still have Python 2.7 when "python --version" is run

Tags: python, python-3.x, macports

After instructing MacPorts to switch to Python 3.4, `python --version` still outputs 2.7.10. Note that "which python" does show that /opt/local/bin is coming before /usr/bin/ in my PATH:

```
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  24 Aug  1 10:00 /opt/local/bin/python -> /opt/local/bin/python2.7
$ sudo port select --list python
Available versions for python:
    none
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python27-apple
    python34
$ sudo port select --set python python34
Selecting 'python34' for 'python' succeeded. 'python34' is now active.
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  24 Aug  1 10:00 /opt/local/bin/python -> /opt/local/bin/python3.4
```

Note how the symlink does change, but the stated version doesn't change. What gives?

Comment: Try reboot the shell after the symlink has changed.

Comment: Yes! This worked. Can you give a short explanation of why the shell doesn't read the symlink afresh each time?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm quite a beginner in GNU/Linux systems, I juts know that when you create an alias for example (in `bash_aliases` file) you have to refresh the bash shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: Run `hash -r`.

---

For speed reasons, shells keep a cache of what executable needs to be run when you type `python` into the shell.

Consider what a shell would have to do without such a cache: For each command (that is not an absolute path) that you enter, the shell would have to

1. go over the entries in `$PATH`, and for each entry
2. issue a `stat(2)` system call to test whether the command exists in the currently searched directory. Remember that this might involve slow rotational disks or even network file systems back when shells were originally developed.

To speed this up, most shells will only do this once for each command until either `$PATH` is changed, or you manually tell the shell to drop the cache (e.g. using `hash -r` in bash, `rehash` in some other shells).

It was news to me that some shells also cache the symlinks, though.

Comment: There's nothing special about symlinks, though: the shell caches the path to the binary, whether that binary is a regular file (i.e., the actual binary) or a symlink to the true, underlying binary.

Comment: Well, `sudo port select --set python python34` changes the target of the `/opt/local/bin/python` symlink, and the shell had `python` mapped to `/opt/local/bin/python`. So if the shell didn't expand that symlink in it's cache, `python --version` should have returned 3.4. It did print 2.7, though, so bash must have had the symlink `/opt/local/bin/python -> python2.7` in cache.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks, I hadn't noticed the contradiction. However, I cannot recreate the issue: `hash -l` lists the cached paths as symlinks, if applicable, and even the following test command makes changing the symlink's target take immediate effect (verified on both Bash v3.2.57 and v4.3.42, run from a folder contained in the PATH): `ln -f -s $(which date) btmp; btmp; ln -s -f $(which whoami) btmp; btmp; rm btmp`.